# How to write tests for a Play Framework Filter?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've written a Filter for my Play application:

```
object MyFilter {
  def apply() = new MyFilter()
}

class MyFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(next: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {

      requestHeader.cookies.get("myCookie") match {
        case Some(cookie) => {
          requestHeader.session + ("importantValue", cookie.value)
          next(requestHeader)
        }
        case None => {
          val importantValue = ... // retrieve the value from somewhere
          requestHeader.session + ("importantValue", importantValue)
          next(requestHeader).map(_.withCookies(Cookie("importantValue", value)))
      }

    }
  }
}
```

There're a lot of examples in the Play documentation about how to write test, but I've no idea how to unit test MyFilter. Can someone help me a little?

Thanks

Torben

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/test/scala/play/filters/headers/SecurityHeadersFilterSpec.scala

Answer (score 6):

The play framework source code shows test for filters.
for example:

```
val filter = SecurityHeadersFilter()
// Play.current is set at this point...
val rh = FakeRequest()
val action = Action(Ok("success"))
val result = filter(action)(rh).run()

header(X_FRAME_OPTIONS_HEADER, result) must beSome("DENY")
```

taken from here [SecurityHeadersFilterSpec.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/test/scala/play/filters/headers/SecurityHeadersFilterSpec.scala)

Answer (score -1):

Not answering your question but `requestHeader.session + ("importantValue", cookie.value)` is never going to do anything. You're creating a new session object and don't do anything with it.

Comment: Oh, yeah ... never tested the code. Hm ... what's the best way to pass my "importantValue" from the Filter to the Controller on the first request?